# How to block all HTTP urls in iOS Application

Tags: ios, xcode, app-transport-security

I searched and found many links which tells to block HTTP and some specific domain or allow specific domain using Transport Security in Plist file
like [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http) and [Application Transport Security](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544).
I used following in my plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

My app consuming APIs and displaying data on views, there is a page in my app where I set server url like https://liveserver.com and http://localserver.com, but when I set url http://localserver.com it still working. And It still working with **true** value. Kindly give me suggestion how to block All HTTP urls and app will only work with HTTPS.

Thanks

Comment: Try deleting the key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`.

Comment: @Aleem What do you mean by "user can set Domain like https://google.com"?
are those links in your app and opening this in browser or webView?

Comment: Google.com is just an example. Actually my app is consuming APIs of our local server like http:/localServer.com and one live server like https:/liveServer.com

Comment: How are you accessing the domains in question?  SFSafariViewController? UIWebView? NSURLConnection?

Comment: @Aleem you need to provide details about how you are trying to connect to the domains above.  ATS only applies in some scenarios.  For example, if you are doing it in a SFSafariViewController, your ATS settings will not apply, since SFSafariViewController is sandboxed separate from your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

For Block all HTTP try

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
     <key>*</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
 </dict>
```

Comment: I don't want to mention "domain.com", I simply want to disallow all HTTP and allow all url with HTTPS

Comment: For Block all HTTP try: not worked!! It still allows to ping

Comment: ping is not using an http connection.  It uses its own protocol and it's own port.  How are you trying to connect to these domains?  Seem my question above if you want answers on how to do what you are asking.